# Rails Active Record - Recently Updated Through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hypothetical situation that demonstrates my problem: Building a web app that allows artists to create "albums" and add "songs" to those albums. 
When a user ads a song to an album, I want that album to show up in a list of recently updated albums.

Problem: I'm not exactly sure how to write this query in Active Record though I assume its possible.

Example: If a new song is added to an album, then I'd like to have this album returned in the result set. Ultimately the result I want is a set of Albums, but that set is dependent upon the sort of its updated children - the song.

Put another way - I want someone to be able to come to a web page and see all of the albums that were recently updated (updated is when a new song is added to the album).

Classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
end 

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :album_songs
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_songs

  # has a release_date field too, which is when the song will be released.
end

class AlbumSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :album
end 

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_song
  has_many :songs, :through => :album_song
end
```

How can I write a query to return all the albums who have had songs that are RELEASED added to them recently? A released song is a song that came out <= NOW().

Additional things to consider. If a user adds three songs to their album, I only want that album to show up once in the list, not three times, iif the song is released. If the song is not released yet, the query should not return this course as updated. Each time a released song is added,  the course would move up in the 'recently updated' list. Therefore I need some sort of unique on this (I think).

I'm not sure this is possible with ActiveRecord. I ultimately just need the `title` and the `id` of the album and then I can construct everything I need from there.

Whats the best way to do this?

Database is Postgres

Comment: Here a conceptual question, it is ok for your app to update your `users.updated_at` field when a song is added?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla No, we can't update that, due to other business reasons.

Comment: And adding a column to `users` to manage this is not an option either?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla it wouldnt work because I also need to base the query off of a date field (release_date) and that is time based.

Answer (score 0):

Use [touch](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) to update Album's updated_at field after a new song is added:

```
class AlbumSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :album, touch: true
end
```

Then, you can use this query to get 10 recent updated albums:

```
Albums.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(10)
```

---

**UPDATE**

To get 10 albums sorted by the last added song (which is already released) you can try this scope:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :sorted_by_recent_song, -> {
    joins(:albums_songs)
    .where('
      albums_songs.updated_at = (
        SELECT MAX(albums_songs.updated_at)
        FROM albums_songs
        JOIN songs ON albums_songs.song_id = songs.id
        WHERE albums_songs.album_id = albums.id
        AND songs.release_date <= NOW()
      )
    ')
    .group(['albums.id', 'albums_songs.id'])
    .order('albums_songs.updated_at DESC')
    .limit(10)
  }
end
```

Comment: Oh man, this is almost it. I totally forgot to include that i need to filter on a release_date field on the song class. I've updated my question. Thank you for this though!

Comment: @DonnFelker I've just updated my answer. Can you look at it? :)

Comment: Running this query as is, gives me an error claiming my from-clause entry from `albums` is missing. If I add the following join, the query will execute but only return 1 record: `JOIN albums ON albums_songs.album_id = albums.id`

Comment: Ok, getting closer. I removed the `MAX` and changed the `.updated_at = ( SELECT...` to `.updated_at IN (SELECT ...`, and now I get 10 results, but I'm seeing repeated albums and not the correct ones. Hmmm. Also albums are repeated because many songs matched the updated_at `IN` clause.

Comment: Could you show me the full error (with the query preview) after running the scope I posted above? Are you sure, you put it into the Album model nor the Song model? Sorry for the late answer.